# Stored Procedure some columns to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I would like to apologize if this has been asked in a different way before. I couldn't find any links specific to this question.

I'm currently learning how to implement GridViews on an ASP.Net web forms application, changing to grid views from a repeater. The repeaters had been binding to some columns retrieved by a stored procedure on our SQL Server and then displaying to the page. Due to the large amount of data, we decided that using the paging feature associated with grid views would improve our performance. However, when I have the grid view bind to the data source, all of the columns from the stored procedure are displayed. I believe I have the syntax correct:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CECreditGridView" runat="server" DataSourceID="testSqlSource" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="100">
  <Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CECredit_Detail.aspx?CECredit_ID={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="CECredit_ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="actionLinkView" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CECredit_Update.aspx?CECredit_ID={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="CECredit_ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="actionLinkEdit" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CECredit_Detail.aspx?CECredit_ID={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="CECredit_ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="actionLinkDelete" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="CECredit_ID"/>
    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Session Title" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CECredit_Detail.aspx?CECredit_ID={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="CECredit_ID" DataTextField="CECredit_Name" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Person" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Person_Update.aspx?Person_ID={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="Person_ID" DataTextField="FullName" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Type" DataNavigateUrlFormatString=“CECreditType_Update.aspx?CECreditType_ID={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="CECreditType_ID" DataTextField="CECreditType_Name" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Status" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CECreditStatus_Update.aspx?CECreditStatus_ID={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="CECreditStatus_ID" DataTextField="CECreditStatus_Name" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Expiration Date" DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" DataField="CECredit_ExpirationDate" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Updated" DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" DataField="CECredit_RecordUpdateDate" />
  </Columns>
  <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Previous" />
</asp:GridView>
```

So my question is, is there a way to only have the called columns display? Or will I need to change the stored procedure to only return the columns I want displayed? We were trying to have the stored procedure stay the same because the code behind used a few of the other columns for validation, etc.

Comment: There is a property of GridView, it's called `AutoGenerateColumns` . Set it to false

Comment: Well I feel pretty dumb, I had even seen that property in a few examples and didn't put two and two together. AutoGenerateColumns was the problem. Thank you